# upstart on 8.04

Tags: upstart, 8.04

My understanding is that upstart is installed on 8.04, but it's different than 10.04.   I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to start/stop/check services from the command line for 8.04.

I'm seeing some scripts in /etc/event.d (e.g.: rcS, which AFAIK starts the old init.d scripts), but I don't have commands like start/stop/status.

Can someone help me put the pieces together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `initctl`? `stop` (et al) are just symlinks on it.

```
oli@bert:~$ /sbin/initctl --help
Usage: initctl [OPTION]... COMMAND [OPTION]... [ARG]...

Options:
      --system                use D-Bus system bus to connect to init daemon
      --dest=NAME             destination well-known name on system bus
  -q, --quiet                 reduce output to errors only
  -v, --verbose               increase output to include informational messages
      --help                  display this help and exit
      --version               output version information and exit

For a list of commands, try `initctl help'.

Report bugs to <upstart-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

I saw your now gone comment. They're all just symlinks!

```
oli@bert:~$ cd /sbin/
oli@bert:/sbin$ ls -l start stop restart reload status
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-27 18:23 reload -> initctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-27 18:23 restart -> initctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-27 18:23 start -> initctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-27 18:23 status -> initctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-09-27 18:23 stop -> initctl
```

I guess `initctl` checks to see what command calls it.